# Ultra/ultimate humans, ancient structures on an alien planet, pig-people

Tags: story-identification, books, audio-book

I can't tell if I suck at Googling or am mixing up a bunch of things... My friend loaned me an audiobook a few years ago and I remember

- There are parallel stories in multiple times ("fractured tandem" narrative)
- Sentient pigs are some characters
- One guy works for some ultra/ultimates(?) (post-humans of some kind)

  - he has a little ship and is supposed to scout worlds
  - finds structures on some alien planet
  - girlfriend kept hostage in some strange contraption
  - his name is that of some religion in another time(?)

It's a part of some series.

Comment: Maybe 'Redemption Ark' by Alastair Reynolds or another title from his Revelation Space series. It's been too long for me to remember the details.

Comment: Some points remind me of Doctor Who. Audiobooks, sure, there are plenty. Jumping around in time, yes. Pig people, yes (in _Daleks in Manhattan_). Post-humans(?), the Time Lords obviously. Little ship, yes, if you count the TARDIS as a little ship. Structures on an alient planet, sure. Companion kept hostage in a strange contraption, oh yeah, often enough. His name though, that eludes me...

Comment: I don't recall time travel, just that there are at least two narratives going on that are separated in time.

Comment: Duke Nukem maybe? ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is in fact [*Absolution Gap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolution_Gap) (2003) by Alastair Reynolds, which has a scout (Quaiche, who forages for alien artefacts) a girlfriend in a strange contraption ( Morwenna in a "scrimshaw suit", trapped in there by Quaiches boss Jasmina), an intelligent "hyperpig" named Scorpio, and is told in multiple times.

Also a religion of sorts plays a fairly big role - Quaiche constructed rolling cathedrals that follow the path of the sun in the sky so they can constantly observe the suns surface in case an alien incursion from another universe that happened early in the novel at the sun should repeat.

Comment: Completely agree with this, having just finished Absolution Gap for the third time last week - there is utterly no doubt, given the description by the OP, that this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "pigs" aspect of it makes me think of "Speaker For the Dead" (1986) by Orson Scott Card, the second book in the *Ender's Game* series.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7967.Speaker_for_the_Dead):

> In this second book in the saga set 3,000 years after the terrible war, Ender Wiggin is reviled by history as the Xenocide--the destroyer of the alien Buggers. Now, Ender tells the true story of the war and seeks to stop history from repeating itself. ...
>
> In the aftermath of his terrible war, Ender Wiggin disappeared, and a powerful voice arose: The Speaker for the Dead, who told the true story of the Bugger War.
>
> Now, long years later, a second alien race has been discovered, but again the aliens' ways are strange and frightening...again, humans die. And it is only the Speaker for the Dead, who is also Ender Wiggin the Xenocide, who has the courage to confront the mystery...and the truth.