# A space ship orbiting a planet, hidden, mistakenly opening a hatch and this way starting a new religion of sky gazers

Tags: story-identification, books

Quite a few years ago (10 or more) I read a (sci-fi) book of a space ship orbiting a planet, hidden, mistakenly opening a hatch and this way starting a new religion of sky gazers.
Monks with eye openers, automatic drip systems to just be able to have their eyes opened all the time.

Anyone remember the title?

Comment: Hi, and welcome! By "book" do you mean a novel or a short story in an anthology? Where did you read it (i.e. school, library, etc) and what country?

This story sounds really interesting so I hope someone is able to provide an answer.

Comment: Vague resemblance to Absolution Gap by Alastair Reynolds (timeframe fits, there is a guy who has his eyes opened all the time looking for aliens and he has build a religion around him).

Comment: That could be it...the cover looks familiar. I'm going to the library...Thanks!

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141013/ultra-ultimate-humans-ancient-structures-on-an-alien-planet-pig-people